# how to remove Dupicates in particular cell in a excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I want to remove duplicate. But that particular duplicate cells alone need to remove. I dont want to remove whole rows of that duplicate value. Do we have option for that in excel 2013.

For example:

We have 2 coloumns below. I need to remove duplicate from 2nd coloumn so no need to remove first coloumn while do the duplication removing part.

```
a 1
b 2
c 3 - Only 3 from the cell needs to remove
d 3
e 4 - Only 4 from the cell needs to remove
f 4
```

Answer should be come like below. it deleted only the particular cell of the duplicate not that full row..

```
a 1
b 2 
c 3
d 
e 4
f
```

Comment: please share some sample data, it's difficult to understand your question now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: I formatted your example, but your question is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should select that particular cells then click on "Remove Duplicate"  button on the data tab.
I examined this solution in Excel with this example:
a
a
a
b
b
c
After I selected the cells that contain "b" I clicked on "Remove Duplicate" and I saw the one of cells with "b" remained but any cells that contain "a" didn't clear.

Comment: I shared with the example please try that

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your example. Please clear it.

Comment: check now i mentioned the answer how i am expecting